# Parser for MIME Type 'text/xml charset=utf-8'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, parsing, restkit

I am using restkit and I have problems parsing an xml:

```
Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/xml charset=utf-8'
Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: text/xml charset=utf-8)
```

Isn't it supported?

Comment: the mime type should be just "text/xml", the charset shouln't be a part of mimetype. Can you change / verify the server API?

Comment: unfortunately I can't. I have been given a call to a server and I had to guess all

Comment: "charset" is a valid parameter for some MIME types; however, it should be preceded by a semicolon, as in "text/xml;charset=utf-8".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't modify the server just register the mimetype with XML parser in RKParserRegistry:

```
[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] setParserClass:[[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeXML] class] 
                                      forMIMEType:@"text/xml charset=utf-8"];
```